# Set a Titlebar Icon for Window (python, turtle module)

Tags: python, icons, turtle-graphics, titlebar, python-turtle

How I can change Titlebar Icon of my Window?
I want to do the Game with 'turtle' module. This is my program code:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()

# What I try:
# wn.iconbitmap("d:\my_icon.ico")

wn.title("My game")
wn.bgcolor('blue')
wn.setup(width=500, height=500)

wn.mainloop()
```

If I do that...:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()._root
wn.iconbitmap("d:\my_icon.ico")
wn.title("My game")

# ...when these lines of code don't work!:
# wn.setup(width=500, height=500)
# wn.bgcolor('blue')

# But I see my icon!

wn.mainloop()
```

Help me please!

Comment: Not sure if this is related: the backslash is used to escape special characters, e.g., "\n" is a newline. Use either another backslash to escape each backslash in the paths (e.g., "d:\\my_icon.ico") or use a raw string like `r"d:\my_icon.ico"` instead.

Comment: oh no ... sorry for the typo ... but that's not the point.